# Invalid response error when installing Viber on PC

Tags: software-installation

I typed on terminal:

```
~$ wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
--2018-06-30 19:54:15--  http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
Resolving download.cdn.viber.com (download.cdn.viber.com)... 2.17.13.45
Connecting to download.cdn.viber.com (download.cdn.viber.com)|2.17.13.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 44397656 (42M) []
Saving to: ‘Viber.zip.1’


Viber.zip.1         100%[===================>]  42,34M  3,97MB/s    in 10s     

2018-06-30 19:54:25 (4,22 MB/s) - ‘Viber.zip.1’ saved [44397656/44397656]
```

then:

```
igor@igor-Easynote-TE69HW:~$ unzip Viber.zip
Archive:  Viber.zip
replace Viber/Sound/DTMF/0.wav? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: error:  in]alid response
```

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The message "`replace Viber/Sound/DTMF/0.wav? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: error:  in]alid response`" leads me to believe that you've installed `Viber` previously (or tried), and have leftovers from previous installations.

`unzip` noticed that a file from the `Viber.zip` archive would, if unzipped, overwrite `Viber/Sound/DTMF/0.wav`, and offered you a choice of actions:

Type `y` to replace the existing file with the one from `Viber.zip`.
Type `n` to keep the old `Viber/Sound/DTMF/0.wav`.
Type `A` to replace this file, and any following files to be overwritten with the files from the archives.
Type `N` to keep the old file, and continue to keep old files, rather than asking again.

You responded with something else, which was invalid.

Rerun the `unzip Viber.zip` and answer with one of the valid choices.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'm installing Viber on Ubuntu 16.04:

```bsh
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
sudo apt install -f

rm viber.deb # optionally remove the installation package
```

If you want to remove it:

```bsh
sudo apt remove viber*
```

---

Because Viver's auto-start option doesn't work as it is expected, I would suggest you my workaround to run Viber at user log-in:

**1.** Copy and paste into a terminal and execute as single command the following lines to create custom `viber.launcher` script:

```bsh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/viber.launcher && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/viber.launcher
#!/bin/sh
sleep 1
killall Viber > /dev/null 2>&1
sleep 1
killall Viber > /dev/null 2>&1
sleep 3
/opt/viber/Viber /dev/null 2>&1 &    # cat /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop
sleep 5
xdotool windowminimize \$(xdotool search --name "Viber" | tail -1)
EOF
```

- `xdotool` is required: `sudo apt install xdotool`
- Tweak the `sleep` values for slow PCs.

**2.** Create Startup Applications entry for the script by using the same technique (do this for each user):

```bsh
cat << EOF | tee $HOME/.config/autostart/viber.launcher.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=viber.launcher
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=ViberCustomLauncher
Name=ViberCustomLauncher
Comment= Launch Viber
EOF
```